# apache permission for php5 folder on linux

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, php5

i have a problem with apache. session_start() error. 
i think my apache have not permission to write and i don't know how fix it.
i run:

```
ls -al /var/lib/ | grep php5
drwx-wx-wt  2 root          root          4096 Apr  4 16:15 php5
```

what can i do?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you sure it stores the sessions in `/var/lib/php5`?
Do you have `root` access? If so, you can fix it yourself, if not, ask your admin to do the same as you would to fix it yourself, namely this:

1. find out who apache runs as (for instance, `www-data`, `apache`, or `httpd`)

   make the session directory writable for that user.

For instance: `ps -ef | egrep -e 'http|apache'` will show on the first column the username of the apache user. On my machine the username is `apache`.

Check the group membership of that user with `id -a apache`

```
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then change the group ownership and permissions on the sessions directory:

`chgrp apache /var/lib/php5/session && chmod g+w /var/lib/php5/session`